# Is there a way to check if a variable equals something in a set of values ? | C

Tags: c

Instead of writing `if(exp[i] =='*' || exp[i] =='/' || exp[i] =='+')` can i write something like this `if(exp[i] == {'*','/','+'})` .But writing this throws me an error, So is there any simple way of doing this ?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. There are no sets in C. But you could simulate a set using an array and then loop through the array (useful if the set is really bug), or use switch/case.

Comment: `switch(exp[i]) case '*': case '/': case '+':`

Comment: You could do something with `strstr()`, but your `if ` or a `switch`, as suggested by @PSkocik, would be definitely faster and easier

Comment: @JackLilhammers strstr or strchr will likely get inlined by decent compilers, so there's no reason a switch is "definitely faster". https://godbolt.org/z/o7xb93 As you can see it didn't even add a branch, nor any function call to strchr.

Comment: @Lundin, you're right about speed, thank you! Still I think the simpler solution it's much more readable. Of course if the string of characters is not defined at compile time `strchr()` becomes better

Comment: thanks guys strchr worked for me @Lundin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `strchr()` function together with a *compound literal*:

```
if( strchr( (char[]){'*','/','+','\0'}, exp[i] ) )
```

Or if you prefer, the far more readable string literal version:

```
if( strchr("*/+", exp[i]) )
```